# add decimal point and thousand separator in to textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am tying to add thousand separator and decimal point to my text box.

I am using below directive also

```
.directive('format', function ($filter) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) {
                return;
            }

            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function () {
                return $filter('number')(ctrl.$modelValue);
            });

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[\,\.]/g, ''),
                    b = $filter('number')(plainNumber);

                elem.val(b);

                return plainNumber;
            });
        }
    };
})
```

this is my  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LCZfd/9/)

i need to modify this. 
When user enter 500,000, it should be like 500,000.00
and user can be enter 5000.50 also.

How i modify this, can u help

Answer (score 0):

Take the decimal placement out of the users control.

```
num = 599993863737
num = str(num).replace('.','')
num = float(num[:len(num)-2]+'.'+num[-2:])


print(num)
5999938637.37
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toFixed()` and `regex`

```js
function currency(el){
  a = parseFloat(el.value);
  a = a.toFixed(2);
  a=a.toString();       
  var b = a.replace(/[^\d\.]/g,'');
  var dump = b.split('.');
  var c = '';
  var lengthchar = dump[0].length;
  var j = 0;
  for (var i = lengthchar; i > 0; i--) {
          j = j + 1;
          if (((j % 3) == 1) && (j != 1)) {
                  c = dump[0].substr(i-1,1) + ',' + c;
          } else {
                  c = dump[0].substr(i-1,1) + c;
          }
  }

  if(dump.length>1){
          if(dump[1].length>0){
                  c += '.'+dump[1];
          }else{
                  c += '.';
          }
  }
  console.log(c);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' onkeyup='currency(this)'>
```